# Which one does rspec run first? spec_helper.rb or db:test:prepare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to implement an additional check for faulty database.yml configurations. In our configuration, we follow the rails database.yml convention, which is basically adding "_#{env}" suffix to the names of the databases. We've had an incident on another project (not rails), where someone forgot to switch databases before running unit tests, causing us to lose data on the staging environment. We hacked a workaround by adding a simple check, which is: if the database name doesn't end with "_test", don't wipe it, don't run unit tests on it.

So what is the right way of implementing this check for rails. I figured I can do it in the spec_helper.rb, but when I ran the tests after I changed the database name, instead of raising the error message that I wrote, it threw:

```
TinyTds::Error: Database 'some_db_name' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

Which means, it connected to the db before spec_helper.rb is loaded. I couldn't find any information on when the db:test:prepare is executed, and didn't ahve the courage to test it with an existing db that doesn't have "_test" suffix.

Is there a hook that I can use for this?

Comment: For starters, `db:test:prepare` is a rake task that sets up the test database schema and it's typically not run as part of startup. Also, I think it's Rails connecting to the database and not RSpec, so you need to put something in the Rails startup, perhaps checking the database name based on the Rails environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Including in your spec_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'
```

line the rspec test should run in test environment looking for test database connection string and therefore run always in test database. Without any problem for others differents environment databases

Comment: That line is already present in my spec_helper.rb file. What I'm trying to do is to check whether the name of the database set for testing is actually a test database.

Comment: I edited the answer changing ||= for =. Before begin test your must force to test environment and always test will run in correct database. The other way is setting environment in command when run test. RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec spec /spec...

Comment: also you must run db:test:prepare before run test.